Mobile Robotics Localization and ROS
I am looking for some good resources to learn ROS as quickly as possible. I am restarting my PhD very shortly after a long break. Also, are there any good resources for the local and global paths, and where is the best place to restart so I can hit the ground running? I am just looking for some good, strong advice.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Hi I would start by doing this quick course:
ROS2 Nav2 [Navigation 2 Stack] - with SLAM and Navigation
It contains:

AMCL Robot Localization
Nav2 Stack, including global and local planners
-Mapping, costmaps, recovery behaviors
-API interface usage
Mobile Robot Navigation

You will learn much more quickly than reading ROS Wiki documentation.
I did, and it is an excellent course. There are also other good courses on Udemy or in The Construct of ROS2.
But this one is very suitable for the needs you mentioned. It is cheap and the professor answers your questions in a very short time (1-2 days).
